# Domain controller not updating Get-ADUser in powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

When looking up an account using `net user jsmith /domain` it will display all the current info about a user and it's password. When I look it up using powershell with Get-ADUser , the information is not accurate. I am guessing this is because they are pointing to a different domain controller, and one did not catch up yet?

Question is: What domain controller is net user using? So that I may make Get-ADUser use the same one.

Better yet, how can I find the fastest domain controller?

Comment: I think `net user` would be using the domain controller that you would see from the command `set logonserver` or `set log` for short. There is not fastest domain controller really. All depends on where the initial change is made and the deisng of your replication sites

Comment: Any way to find out what controller that is?

Comment: I was trying to tell you. The output of the cmd `set log` should tell you that.

Comment: Strange that this worked with command prompt but not in powershell. Any idea why?

Comment: In short because it is not a powershell command. `Set` in powershell is an alias for `Set-Variable`. In PowerShell `$env:LOGONSERVER` would be a better fit. Didnt occur to me to suggest it at first

Comment: That's okay it works.

Comment: Could you provide some example as to what data is innacurate? Maybe the data is just presented differently and you **interpret** it as being innacurate...?

Comment: @RobertRossmann If I looked up a user with the 'net user' command, it would show they changed their password today. If I used Get-ADUser, it would show that their password was still expired.

Comment: I got it, I got it - I know, I know! Posting my answer in a moment...:)

Answer (score 1):

So I was wrong about my assumption see [Robert's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28442339/3829407). Using that knowledge properly I can salvage this answer.

So, If you want cohesion between the `net user` and `Get-Aduser` you could try something like this:

```
$pdc = (((nltest /dclist:domainname | ?{$_ -match "\[PDC\]"}).Trim()) -Split '\s')[0]
Get-ADUser -Identity someguy -Server $pdc
```

As for picking the fastest domain controller your computer should have already been told which controller is appropriate for it to use. Changes you make in the same active directory site should replicate quickly. If you are making changes across AD sites then you will have to wait as long as you have set in your site to site replication settings.

Comment: I am pretty sure `Get-ADUser` uses the same env var (*LOGONSERVER*) as `net user`... It certainly does not randomly select one for each command from DNS, that would break all Hell loose.

Comment: @RobertRossmann I would think that to be correct. Then my replication comments could be of use.

Comment: Well the problem kind of does not compute for me... If we agree that both commands use the same DC, why would replication be of any concern? If replication is of no concern then why by the nine divines is the information not identical?

Comment: @RobertRossmann In hindsight you are right. I was trying to figure out a reason why the two  would be different using the op's assumtions for my basis. After reading your comment I realize my code is redundant.

Comment: Well, turns out we were both wrong - `net user` does **not** use the logonserver.:) It uses the primary domain controller - see my answer below if you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

The `net user` command, when given the `/domain` switch, [operates on the Primary Domain Controller](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251394), which may not necessarily be your current logon server which, on the other hand, is used by `Get-ADUser`.

And the reason why you are seeing different information is that replication of this change has not occured yet between these two.

- To see your logon server, in cmd, do `set logonserver`.
- To see your primary domain controller (PDC), do `nltest /dclist:example.org` (`nltest` requires some Active Directory tools to be installed, [see the docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731935.aspx))

Comment: I saw that put ignored it since true PDC's don't exist anymore. That is obviously not completely correct. I tried to salvage my answer with your findings. Good work.

Comment: Well, when I ran that command, it listed all the domain controllers, and there was one in the list that had [PDC] next to it. Strange thing is that this was the exact domain controller I was getting my data from, but it still is not updated and shows inaccurate info. Is there some caching going on or maybe just some maintenance? Also, the command should be nltest /dclist:example.org -- you have an extra space.